# Как организовать правильное хранение

Tags: python

Есть 4 параметра, которые я беру из входящих писем по крону.

```
Тема письма
Тело письма
Время
Дата
```

Хочу хранить их в какой то коллекции. Пока не пойму до конца. Я беру данные из почты, предварительно смотрю уникальные значения - пихаю в `google spreadsheet`. Стоит вопрос - как организовать хранение этих данных. Поднимать `Mysql` для таких простых данных? Как пушкой по воробьям. `Sqlite` не нравится своей скоростью. Хранить в памяти всё? Не знаю даже. Тогда в какую коллекцию пихать*? Список, словарь...

Comment: А что не так со скоростью sqlite? Какие у вас объемы данных и требования по скорости их обработки если sqlite3 не справляется? :)

Comment: Поиск писем предполагается по одному ключу или по нескольким? Каковы предполагаемые операции с коллекцией писем?

Comment: для того чтобы дать адекватный ответ надо понимать как данное хранилище данных будет использоваться. А именно: 1. О каком объеме данных идет речь? 2. Сколько пользователей будут __одновременно__ искать в БД? 3. Сколько пользователей будут __одновременно__ писать в БД? 4. По каким полям нужен поиск? 5. Нужен ли полнотекстовый поиск? 6. Как часто данные будут добавляться / изменяться?